# AWS Lambda Java Timeout

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I created an AWS lambda function consisting of their bare minimum example for a custom Alexa skill. I cloned this repository and followed the instructions accordingly: https://github.com/alexa/skill-samples-java/tree/master/helloworld

When I try running a test request in the AWS console I get the following error:
[image: aws console error]

After hours of testing, I have no idea why it fails. I mean it's their official git repo - one would assume the stuff on there is working.

Can someone advice on this?

Comment: Did you setup the lambda in us-east?

Comment: You may want to try increasing your Lambda timeout under "Basic Settings".  The default is 3 seconds and that may not be long enough.

Comment: Increasing the timeout did it - I am glad that Amazon bothered putting it in their basics tutorial for java : ^)

Answer (score 0):

Java needs JVM to be started and it can take long time depending on the memory since the [CPU is also proportional to memory](https://engineering.opsgenie.com/how-does-proportional-cpu-allocation-work-with-aws-lambda-41cd44da3cac) settings. Even with 3GB RAM, the cold-start value of JVM is aronud 1 seconds and if you have too many classes to load you can easily hit 3 seconds. However, after the cold start, AWS caches your lambda container and freezes it, and activates it upon new requests and it can response much quicker.